# mapserver esriGeometryPolyline filter data by specifying bounding box

Tags: python, gis, arcgis-server

I am attempting to filter a ARCGIS REST MapServer layer by specifying a bounding box from a GeoDataFrame, once I was successful but not anymore.

I can filter the layer service by specifying/filtering with a column value, like:

```
rest_service_url = "https://srv.doris.at/arcgis/rest/services/Basisdaten/Basisdaten_Spezial/MapServer/3/query?"

params = {
    #"geometryType": "esriGeometryEnvelope",
    "where": "OBJECTID=7066",
    "outFields": "*",
    "f": "pjson"                        
}


response = requests.get(rest_service_url, params=params)

# Check if the request was successful (HTTP status code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()

print(data)
```

but when I try to filter by bounding box (I repeat, I managed it once, but idk why it doesn't work anymore):

```
bbox = map_bbox[1].geometry.total_bounds

# Define the bounding box extent
extent = f"{bbox[0]},{bbox[1]},{bbox[2]},{bbox[3]}"


params = {
    "geometry": extent,                 # Bounding box extent
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryEnvelope",
    "spatialRel": "esriSpatialRelIntersects",
    "outFields": "*",
    "f": "pjson"
}
```

I've checked everything in detail, including the bounding box. The bounding box is in EPSG:31255, same as the service is:

```
print(extent)
'44801.24375471848,343279.68052187003,47325.0478822446,345798.64210799057'
```